# matplotlib switch between figures

Tags: matplotlib, switch-statement, figure

I want to display different figures. For this I have to switch between them.

figure(1), one figure, should have all lines from the for loop
figure(2), every loop iteration one figure

````
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplots(dpi=96)
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

for #anything... :
    #load new line values...
        plt.figure(2)
    ax = plt.subplots(dpi=96)
    twin1 = plt.twinx()
            
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(x, y, ".-")

    plt.figure(2)
    ax.plot(x, y, ".-")
    twin1.plot(x2, y2, ".-")
    plt.title('single plot for evere line')
    ax.set(xlabel='...')   
    twin1.yaxis.label.set_color('r')
    twin1.set(ylabel='y')
    ax.grid(visible = True,
             which   = 'major',
             axis    = 'x',
             linewidth = 0.4
             )
    plt.tight_layout()          
    plt.show() 
plt.figure(1)
plt.tight_layout()   
plt.show()```


There are some examples in the web. But figure(2) uses the twinx, and because of this it don't works. What I'm doing wrong?
````

Comment: Before trying to display multiple figures at the same time, have you tried any of them individually? Was it working?

Comment: The majority of the problem probably comes for switching between the [implicit](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#the-implicit-pyplot-interface) and [explicit](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#the-explicit-axes-interface) API. Don't do that. The only time the implicit API should be used, is if you're doing a simple single figure/axes. Otherwise, always use the explicit API.

Comment: @fdireito : I had to change the code to handle the figures -> so the code has not worked individually as you can see it above.

Answer (score 1):

@TrentonMcKinney, ok I haven't seen very clear the difference of implicit and explicit API. But now I read the docu. I tried it now with the explicit API, I fighted with some properties ... :) but now it looks good.

Thanks for you recommondation!

This is the new written code example is maybe helpful for other user:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y1_all = [[1.1, 1.2, 1.3 ,1.4],[2.1, 2.2, 2.3 ,2.4]]
y2 = [10, 12, 13, 13.3]

fig1 = plt.figure()
fig1.set_dpi(96)
fig1ax = fig1.subplots()
fig1ax.set_title('fig1: all lines')

for y in  y1_all:
    fig2 = plt.figure()
    fig2.set_dpi(96)
    fig2ax = fig2.subplots()
    fig2twin1 = fig2ax.twinx()        
    
    fig1ax.plot(x, y, ".-")

    fig2ax.plot(x, y, ".-")
    fig2twin1.plot(x, y2, ".-r")
    fig2ax.set_title('fig2: single line')
    fig2ax.set(xlabel='...')   
    fig2twin1.yaxis.label.set_color('r')
    fig2twin1.set(ylabel='fig2 y2 axis')
    fig2ax.grid(visible = True,
             which   = 'major',
             axis    = 'x',
             linewidth = 0.4
             )
    fig2ax.grid(visible = True,
             which   = 'major',
             axis    = 'y',
             color   = 'm',
             linewidth = 0.4
             )
    fig2twin1.grid(visible = True,
             which   = 'major',
             axis    = 'y',
             color   = 'r',
             linewidth = 0.4
             )  
    fig2.tight_layout()          
    fig2.show() 
    
fig1.tight_layout()   
fig1.show()
```

Do you have some more improvement suggestions?